# gpu on riser on main slot pcie x16 won't show in device manager?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, gpu, pci-express

I am trying to run my rtx 3070ti on this mobo but when I check in the device manager there is not rtx 3070 ti just onboard graphics and some unknown adapter. Here is what the rig looks like. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

this is what my rig looks like.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxQ9z.jpg

mobo
https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/MPG-Z490-GAMING-PLUS/Specification

Answer (score 0):

In your BIOS, set the mode for the PCI slot with your riser to "Gen3".